# What is the best way to reset a column on daily basis with thousands of users?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, inertiajs

I am using Laravel with the project I am currently working, the question above is one of the necessary thing that needs to be implement on the project.

So there should be a column that needs to reset everyday for all users and this project may contain hundreds or thousands of users and what should be the best way to do it that will not cause performance issues or server overloading.

I wanted to use Laravel's own scheduling but I not sure if this is quite the right thing to do.

Please help :)

Comment: You may define a CronJob in server and create Laravel Schedule to check it daily. Of course for more data your server will get more load. That's why try to do it during the timeslot when users are least busy with your site. To optimize your query you should add `index`es to table columns that are gonna checked for basis.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a job and schedule a command for this. So, with command even if you have to reset the column manually you can just run this command.
So, what you would do is:

```
php artisan make:command ResetColumnCommand
```

and, to generate a job:

```
php artisan make:job ResetColumnJob
```

and then, inside the job write the logic which would be similar to this:

```
$query = SomeModel::query();

$query->chunk(100, function($data) {
  $data->update([
    // Set the column to null
  ]);
});
```

Since, you're sure that there can be alot of records, you should definitely use chunk in order to reduce your memory usage.

NOTE: If you're applying any condition before chunk on a column. e.g: You want only records where that column is not already null then you should use `chunkById` instead of `chunk` because there are some issues that can be encountered with chunk and unexpected results.

Comment: Thank you for the insight. I think this is the best way to do it.

Comment: No problem, kindly upvote/accept the answer So if other comes to this question they can see this answer.

Comment: My apologies, I can't as of the moment but will definitely upvote this once I'm able.